# Swift equivalent of Python Dictionary setdefault() Method

Tags: python, swift, dictionary

The `setdefault()` method on Python dictionary sets the value for a key if the key is missing in the dictionary and returns that value. [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_setdefault.asp).

Is there a similar method available for Swift dictionary?

I tried this:

```
var dic1 = ["a": 1]
let defVal = dic1["b", default: 2]
print(defVal) // prints 2
print(dic1) // prints ["a": 1]
// However, I need ["a": 1, "b": 2]
```

Comment: No but you can always set that value from the start, that would make it default

Comment: I'd like to set the key only on certain conditions. There's no point setting the value from the start.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension with setDefault declared

```
extension Dictionary {
    mutating func setDefault(_ key: Key, value: Value) -> Value {
        if let existing = self[key] { return existing }

        self[key] = value
        return value
    }
}
```

Example

```
var d1: [String: Int] = ["A": 4]
d1["C"] = 13
d1.setDefault("B", value: 42)

print(d1)
```

Outputs

> ["A": 4, "C": 13, "B": 42]

Comment: That is not an equivalent to pythons setdefault(). Python does only one search into the dictionary, while the suggested extension searches twice. That is twice slower. Besides, pythons return the existing value or the newly inserted one

Comment: @VadimGoryunov Since performance wasn't part of the question I am going to ignore that part but it was strange that my function didn't return a value so I have fixed that, thanks.